# How to remember something from a loop after the loop is done?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, while-loop, get

I am trying to read a file and then have it print specific integers (Retail Prices) that I put into a dictionary from that file. This part I got. But when I try and print the Retail Prices outside of the loop, it cannot find them. If I include it within the loop, the file only reads one line! Help!!

```
while line != '':
    line = fh.readline()
    line = line.replace(',', '')
    line = line.replace('"', '')
    line = line.replace(';', ',')
    linesplit = line.split(',')
    linesplit = line.split(',')
    dictionary = dict(zip(headerItems, linesplit))
    RetailPrice = dictionary.get('retailprice')
    print(RetailPrice)
    RetailPrice = Retail_Prices
    z = z + 1
    if z == 4:
        price = 'goodbye'
        price = input('Enter a valid Retail Price to find all products below that price, or type anything else to exit: ')
        print(Retail_Prices)
```

Comment: When asking a code-related question, it is always necessary to add a tag for the specific programming language  you're using. Please [edit] your post to add that tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the keyword dictionary outside the while loop set to None or empty dict and then over-ride it in the while loop.